# juniper ex2200c get temperature via snmp

Tags: snmp, juniper, junos

I have a juniper ex2200c and am trying to get the temperature via snmp.
I'v tried [this](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB17526) tutorial by juniper, but my switch doesn't seem to answer.

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c foobar23 192.168.1.10 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.5
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.5.1.1.0.0 = ""
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.5.2.1.1.0 = STRING: "Power Supply: Power Supply 0 @ 0/0/*"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.5.7.1.0.0 = STRING: "FPC: EX2200-C-12T-2G @ 0/*/*"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.5.8.1.1.0 = STRING: "PIC: 12x 10/100/1000 Base-T @ 0/0/*"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.5.8.1.2.0 = STRING: "PIC: 2x (10/100/1000 Base-T or GE SFP) @ 0/1/*"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.5.9.1.0.0 = STRING: "Routing Engine 0"
```

My routing engine should be `9.1.0.0`, so when looking at `1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.7.9.1.0.0`, which should give me the temperature, I get:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c foobar23 192.168.1.10 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.7.9.1.0.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.9.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
```

Also when asking less specific I get the following:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c foobar23 192.168.1.10 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1.7  
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.1.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.2.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.7.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.8.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.8.1.2.0 = Gauge32: 0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.9.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
```

But there must be some temperature sensors:

```
root@jun1> show chassis environment 
Class Item                           Status     Measurement
Power FPC 0 Power Supply 0           OK        
Temp  FPC 0 GEPHY1                   OK         25 degrees C / 77 degrees F
      FPC 0 GEPHY2                   OK         35 degrees C / 95 degrees F
      FPC 0 GEPHY3                   OK         35 degrees C / 95 degrees F
      FPC 0 GEPHY4                   OK         30 degrees C / 86 degrees F
```

How can I get the environment Temperature of this switch using snmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.2/information-products/pathway-pages/ex-series/system-monitoring.pdf) on page 10(PDF Page 24):

> Temp is unavailable for an EX2200-C switch.

I Also was reading the correct MIB:

> ```
> jnxOperatingTemp OBJECT-TYPE
>    SYNTAX          Gauge32
>    MAX-ACCESS      read-only
>    STATUS          current
>    DESCRIPTION
>            "The temperature in Celsius (degrees C) of this 
>            subject.  Zero if unavailable or inapplicable."
>    ::= { jnxOperatingEntry 7 }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Those you listed on the third section:

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.1.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.2.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.7.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0
 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.8.1.1.0 = Gauge32: 0
 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.8.1.2.0 = Gauge32: 0
 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.2636.3.1.13.1.7.9.1.0.0 = Gauge32: 0

are definitely the "OK" states in the "Status" Column.

You need to look at everything below 
1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.13.1 
- all I can say without that same walk or the same switch :)